# Cannot open file "app/tests/php/Test.php"

Tags: php, unit-testing

When I run the PHP unit test using Git Bash it gives me this message.
Cannot open file "**`app/tests/php/Test.php`**"
this file is in the `path` of **`app/tests/php/Model/Blocks/Test.php`**.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use absolute paths, so that it doesn't try to resolve the pathname based on the current working directory.

Autoloading usually takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the command `phpunit --filter`